# Google cloud function don't get triggered

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to trigger a google cloud function when a path of my hosting web site is reached.

So, I have added this on my **firebase.json**

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html",
    "function": "app"
  }
```

here is my function called **"app"** :

```
[...]
server.get('*', (req:any,res:any) => {
 const isBot = detectBot(req.headers['user-agent']);

 if(isBot) {
     const botUrl = generateUrl(req);

     nf(`${renderUrl}/${botUrl}`)
     .then((r: { text: () => any; }) => r.text())
     .then((body: { toString: () => any; }) => {
         res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=300, s-maxage=600');
         res.set('Vary','User-Agent');
         res.send(body.toString())
     });
 } else {
    nf(`https://${appUrl}`)
    .then((r: { text: () => any; }) => r.text())
    .then((body: { toString: () => any; }) => {
        res.send(body.toString());
    });
 }


});


exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(server);
```

The **"app"** function and website are deployed but when i reach an url the **"app"** function don't get triggered.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "rewrites" section isn't properly set up. You specify both a destination ("/index.html") and a function parameter. Here's an example rewrites that will direct requests to `/function-url` to your `app` function and other requests (undefined or "/foo" and "/foo/**") to your `index.html`:

```
"rewrites": [ {
    // Serves index.html for requests to files or directories that do not exist
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }, {
    // Serves index.html for requests to both "/foo" and "/foo/**"
    // Using "/foo/**" only matches paths like "/foo/xyz", but not "/foo"
    "source": "/foo{,/**}",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }, {
    // calls your app function for requests to "/function-url"
    "source": "/function-url",
    "function": "app"
  } ]
```

More info on how to configure rewrites [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites).